connect sides by arrows in any contour, polygonal figure, closed curve, etc
I have the following and I want to make the figure look like its one piece,  without separate parts. I want in general, sketching any contour to be able to draw arrows from one side to the other in a more compact way. indeed, here I have started by drawingthe arrows and connecting the end points, but i d like first to draw the contour and after to draw to arrows.
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
    set arrow inside={end/.initial=>, opt/.initial=},
    /pgf/decoration/Mark/.style={
        mark/.expanded=at position #1 with
        {
            \noexpand\arrow[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/opt}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}
        }
    },
    arrow inside/.style 2 args={
        set arrow inside={#1},
        postaction={
            decorate,decoration={
                markings,Mark/.list={#2}
            }
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=1]
        \node[label=below:$$] () at (-0.5,0.7) {};
        \node[label=below:$$] () at (1,0.8){};
        \draw[black,xshift=0.1cm] plot [smooth,tension=1]
        coordinates {(-0.5,0.7) (0,1) (0.8,0.7)  (1.1,0.68)}
        [arrow inside={end=stealth,opt={blue,scale=0.5}}{0.35}];
        \draw[black,yshift=-0.16cm,xshift=0.1cm] plot [smooth,tension=1]
        coordinates {(-0.5,0.7) (0,1) (0.8,0.7)  (1.1,0.68)}
        [arrow inside={end=stealth,opt={blue,scale=0.5}}{0.35}];
        \draw[black,yshift=-0.28cm,xshift=0.1cm] plot [smooth,tension=1]
        coordinates {(-0.5,0.7) (0,1) (0.8,0.7)  (1.1,0.68)}
        [arrow inside={end=stealth,opt={blue,scale=0.5}}{0.35}];
        \draw[black,yshift=-0.42cm,xshift=0.1cm] plot [smooth,tension=1]
        coordinates {(-0.5,0.7) (0,1) (0.8,0.7)  (1.1,0.68)}
        [arrow inside={end=stealth,opt={blue,scale=0.5}}{0.35}];
       \draw[black,xshift=0.1cm] plot [smooth,tension=1]
        coordinates {(-0.5,0.7) (-0.5,0.7-.16)
        (-0.5,0.7-.28) (-0.5,0.7-.42)};
        \draw[black,xshift=0.1cm] plot [smooth,tension=1]
        coordinates {(1.1,0.68) (1.1,0.68-.16)
        (1.1,0.68-.28) (1.1,0.68-.42)};
     
    \end{scope}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Could you provide a sketch of what you want?

sure, let me do it for you

@SandyG i have edited it now

Here is a macro \contour that takes 1 optional and 5 mandatory arguments:
\contour[<tikz options>]
    {<number of lines>}
    {<start path>}
    {<end path>}
    {<bottom path>}
    {<top path>}

<tikz options> include color, line width, possibly other things.
<number of lines> does not include the top and bottom paths.
<start path> and <end path> are the sides of the region the arrows point from and to respectively.
<bottom path> and <top path> must originate and terminate at the respective points of <start path> and <end path>.
The paths should be code that would normally follow \draw in a tikzpicture, but without the semicolon.
For example,
\contour[blue, thick]
    {8}
    {(0,0) to[bend left] (2,6)}
    {[looseness=2] (4,1) to[out=45, in=225] (5,5)}
    {(0,0) -- (4,1)}
    {(2,6) to[bend right] (5,5)}

will produce the following image:

This idea is to use a style (I called it marks) to mark coordinates on the start path and end path. Then make a smooth plot between corresponding coordinates through 4 additional points interpolated between the top and bottom paths. Note, this works poorly when the region is very non-convex.
Here is the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, calc}
\tikzset{
    marks/.style 2 args={
        postaction=decorate, 
        decoration={
            markings, mark=between positions {1/(#1+1)} and {(#1)/(#1+1)} step {1/(#1+1)} with {
                \coordinate[name=#2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}];
            }
        }
    },
    midarrow/.style={postaction=decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}}
}

\newcommand{\contour}[6][]{% #1=tikz options, #2=num lines, #3=start, #4=end, #5=bottom, #6=top
    \draw[marks={#2}{A}, #1] #3;
    \draw[marks={#2}{B}, #1] #4;
    \draw[marks={4}{C}, midarrow, #1] #5;
    \draw[marks={4}{D}, midarrow, #1] #6;
    \foreach \l in {1,...,#2}{
        \draw[smooth, midarrow, #1] plot coordinates {(A\l)
            ($($(A\l)!{.2}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C1)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D1)$)$)
            ($($(A\l)!{.4}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C2)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D2)$)$)
            ($($(A\l)!{.6}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C3)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D3)$)$)
            ($($(A\l)!{.8}!(B\l)$)!.5!($(C4)!{\l/(#2+1)}!(D4)$)$)
            (B\l)};
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\contour[blue, thick]{8}
    {(0,0) to[bend left] (2,6)}
    {[looseness=2] (4,1) to[out=45, in=225] (5,5)}
    {(0,0) -- (4,1)}
    {(2,6) to[bend right] (5,5)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


if I draw a vertical curve line through the contour, how can I mark intersection points?

I have created a separated question. Right on time=)
